# How to rename multiple files in directory?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I have many files in directory with name like

```
injector.cpython-33.pyo
PregnancyMegaMod.cpython-33.pyo
```

I need to cut from them `.cpython-33` piece, ie after rename files must be like

```
injector.pyo
PregnancyMegaMod.pyo
```

How to write Batch File or PowerShell script?

Comment: You asked for DOS. Perhaps tag for PowerScript and ask for it, You need some time to learn it, but I think you will benefit from it.

Comment: The DOS `REN` command can't handle this. You're using long filenames, which suggests you're on Windows, which suggests PowerShell is available. Is it?

Comment: no difference, dos or PS... All ways are possible...

Comment: It's a one-liner in PowerShell, but contractually, we can't help you unless you tag and pose your question correctly. If you want to know how to do this in PowerShell, edit your question accordingly. Otherwise some poor soul will have to slave over a batch file to accomplish it.

Comment: Edition of the post done.

Comment: DOS is a operating system, what you are asking for are Batch Files. It even says in the description for [tag:DOS] that you should not use that tag when talking about batch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pyo" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '.cpython-33','' }
```

Comment: Excellent, and shorter even than what I had in mind. :-) You may want to use `"*.cpython-33.pyo"` as the filter, though, otherwise it will pointlessly try to rename files that are already OK.

Comment: Excellent! Accept your own answer so the question will shop up as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of the files have additional dots (in other words, no files like "a.b.cpython-33.pyo"), then you could use something like the following:

```
ren *.cpython-33.pyo" "??????????????????????????????????????????.pyo"
```

There must be as many `?` as the longest name before `.cpython=33.pyo"`. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for more info.

If there may be additional dots, then you could use my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) -  a hybrid JScript/batch script that performs rename operations using regular expression replacement. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jren "\.cpython-33\.pyo$" ".pyo" /i
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*.pyo") DO FOR %%b IN ("%%~na") DO IF /i "%%~xb"==".cpython-33" ECHO(REN "%%~fa" %%~nb.pyo"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Obviously, the crux of the method is the `for %%a` line.

For each file matching the mask in the chosen directory, get the name part, and with that name part, extract the "name" part. If the "extension" part is the expected string, then build the rename command.

Comment: You could eliminate the need for IF with `"%sourcedir%\*.cpython-33.pyo"` in the first FOR statement. That file mask cannot match a short 8.3 name, so it should be safe.